# Updating named_scope :all for new ActiveRecord format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, formatting

I have been upgrading named scopes to scopes following this guide http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface. The one thing I have run into in the code I am working with that I have not seen in any examples is how do deal with

```
named_scope :all, <ect>
```

The closest example I have seen is in the m.onkey.org guide which is

```
named_scope :red, :conditions => { :colour => 'red' }
```

to
  `scope :red, :conditions => { :colour => 'red' }`

So would the same idea apply, making my new code

```
scope :all, <ect>
```

or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope `.all` is reserved since ActiveRecord allows you to retrieve all the entries with the same method:

```
User.all #=> returns ALL the users existing in the DB
```

You should rename your scope to a different name.

Also, you don't have to precise the `conditions` keyword. Here is part of codes I'm using in my projects:

```
scope :ordered, order(:name)
scope :with_color, lambda{ |color| where( color: color.try(:to_s) ) }
# this lambda scope is usable by: 
# Model.with_color(:red)
```

Comment: The conditions bit I understand. when you say I should rename my scope do you mean I should replace `:all` with `:foobar`. If so would I need change 'Object.all' to 'Object.foobar` in the code?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't know what is the purpose of your scope `:all`, but it interfer with the ActiveRecord's `.all` I think